# How to check final price or special price is valid or expire on magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, price, special-price

I am trying to add a condition for checked the special price is valid or not for list page but did not able to find.

Answer (score 0):

After Few Time I found at last:-
   $specialPriceFromDate = $_product->getData('special_from_date');
                    $specialPriceToDate = $_product->getData('special_to_date');
                    $today =  time();

```
                if ($specialprice && ($_product->getData('price') > $_product->getData('final_price'))):
                    if($today >= strtotime( $specialPriceFromDate) && $today <= strtotime($specialPriceToDate) || 
                        $today >= strtotime( $specialPriceFromDate) && is_null($specialPriceToDate)):
            ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use getFinalPrice() with product object.
eg.
`$_product->getFinalPrice();` This will gives price if special price if it applicable otherwise gives regular price.

Comment: it give but after special price expire also applicable, I want not selected if sepcial price gonna be expired

Comment: you can find start date and end date in print_r($_product); then compare date as if(strtotime($date1))<strtotime($date2)))

Comment: This is not true, it will return whatever the final price is there. If no special price, it will return the original price as final price.